# how to tar without the parent directory but with the last directory

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to tar a directory without the parent directories and I have found a solution so far which removes the parent directories and tar all the files under a directory called (DIR) to a DIR.tar.gz file using the following:

```
tar -cvzf $DIR.tar.gz -C $path/$DIR .
```

But if I want to untar the tared file, it will untar all the files in the current directory, however, I want to be able to tar the dir in a way which when I use tar -xzvf, it will untar it into folder called DIR. IT should be simple, but I am not able to find the solution on the net. Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
tar -cvzf $DIR.tar.gz -C $path ./$DIR
```

This should change the directory to your folder path (-C) and only include the relative directory ($DIR) that you're trying to archive.

Comment: This does not work, it complains that the file or directory does not exists overthought it does.   tar: ./AnA: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: I _believe_ I've reproduced your problem. I get the same error if I use the wrong value for $path. You'll want to make sure the value for -C is the parent directory of the directory you want to archive. For example, if you want to archive the code directory that exists at `/home/user/code/`, then you'll use `tar -cvzf code.tar.gz -C /home/user/ ./code`.

Comment: Thanks, I was also stuck on the "-C" argument.  The problem was that I had to specify a directory path relative to my "-C" argument.